# How to make Navbar fully responsive for mobile. Nav-links missing. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get my navbar fit on the screen when viewing on mobile. I can get the logo to shrink but I cannot get links to change size so that half of the navbar doesn't cut off.

Here is my Nav code followed by the css.

**NAV**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-dark">
  <div class="container relative">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}">
        <img class="image-fluid" id="vswlogo" src="{% static 'images/Artboard_3.png' %}"/>
      </a>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    body {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #portfoliogrid1 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #portfoliogrid1 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #portfoliogrid1 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #portfoliogrid1 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #portfoliogrid2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #portfoliogrid2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #portfoliogrid2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #portfoliogrid2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }


  /* Fonts */
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap");

  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding-top: px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
  } 
  h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  p {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }


  /* MISC */
  .container-banner {
    margin: ;
  }

  hr {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .banner-image {
    text-align: center;
  }


  /* Body */
  body {
    background-image: url("{% static 'images/purple.jpg' %}");
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Portfolio Columns & Images */
  .arrow-down {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .arrow-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #portfoliothumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }
  #portfoliogrid1 {
    margin-right: -58px;
  }
  #portfoliogrid2 {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
  row {
    margin: 8px -16px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }


  /* Navbar */
  .navbar {
    margin: -1% -1% 1% -1%;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.7em;
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .navbar-logo-centered .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
  }
  .navbar img {
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    top: -50px;
    left: -35px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  }

  #vswlogo:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
```

Please excuse the amount of @media for my website body, I am still trying to filter out which one of them I need to keep and remove. If anyone has any ideas to what i'm missing or even doing wrong, i'd really appreciate to hear them. I'm still learning as you can tell.

Comment: If you want the font size to change on smaller screens, you'll need to add that to the appropriate media queries.  You're also using the navbar-expand class, which may hide nav-links on mobile in Bootstrap.  Use your Inspect tool in your browser to look at the CSS and figure out where they're being hidden.

Comment: @RiverTam thank you for your reply. I have tried a media querie in my css using font-size: for nav-links and it changed nothing. Could it be that expand is the  cause of the problem. I could be wrong but I think I read that using expand was the correct way to make sure it is responsive when using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for a standard mobile view by amending navbar-expand > navbar-expand-lg and adding @media code to center the nav-links and reduce font size. Still working on a fix for desktop view on mobile but I answered my own question above.